# I need to pull a PR locally before it is merged

Tags: git

Another Team Member created a PR in AzDO.  I want to run the merged code locally before I approve or reject the PR.

The PR is #14821.  I can see it in AzDO it's PR #14821
[The PR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS8WT.png)

the documentation all tells me to do the following:
git fetch origin pull/14821/head:temp_branch
But I always get the following:
fatal: couldn't find remote ref pull/14821/head

I can pull other branches and I'm clearly connected to the origin.

What gives?  Can I run the merged code before I merge it into Master?

Comment: Why don't you just pull/fetch your branch instead of specifying `pull/14821/head`? Wouldn't it be easier to `git fetch` and then `checkout` `temp_branch`.

Comment: Try `git ls-remote | grep 14821` to find the exact ref name, and then use `git fetch origin $refname:temp_branch` to fetch the pr head and create `temp_branch`.

Comment: Fetch the PR branch instead by git fetch (fetches the new branches )-> git checkout pr_branch_name (Code checkout  and  mark it as your working branch) :)

Comment: Hi @MatthewNitchalsQ, How are things going? Is the suggestion in my answer helpful to you? Please have a try with it. Any update, feel free to tell us.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with the steps below, they can work fine as expected:

1. Create a folder in your local directory, and name the folder with the repository name.

   [image]
2. Open Git Bash in the folder created at above step, and execute the following Git commands in sequence.

   - Initialized an empty Git repository in the folder.

     ```
     git init
     ```

     [image]
   - Connect to remote repository.

     ```
     git remote add origin <Repository_URL>
     ```

     [image]
   - Fetch the PR merge branch (**`refs/remotes/pull/<PR_ID>/merge`**) from remote.

     ```
     git fetch --force --tags --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull/<PR_ID>/merge:refs/remotes/pull/<PR_ID>/merge
     ```

     OR

     ```
     git fetch --force --tags --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin +refs/pull/<PR_ID>/merge:refs/remotes/pull/<PR_ID>/merge
     ```

     [image]
   - Checkout the latest version on PR merge branch into the local folder.

     ```
     git checkout --progress --force refs/remotes/pull/<PR_ID>/merge
     ```

     [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the checkout task of validation builds. They use the following commands:

```
git fetch --force --tags --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull/<PR_ID>/merge:refs/remotes/pull/<PR_ID>/merge

git checkout --progress --force refs/remotes/pull/<PR_ID>/merge
```